# When to use Microsoft Test Manager?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I'm new to testing and looking into coded ui testing. I noticed that there are two options 1) using the Visual Studio and record the actions from there and then generated the code 2) use the Microsoft Test Manager and do the recording. I'm curious to know what is the advantage of using Microsoft Test Manager? Is there anything that I can't do if I use solely the Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: I worked on Visual Studio at Microsoft)

Microsoft Test Manager is useful when you're a large organisation and have a team of dedicated testers (non-SDET testers), Test Manager gives you a much simpler environment that requires far less user training and also means testers don't need access to the project source code.

If you're doing SDET work, developing your own automated testing or in a small team then you'll be fine with Visual Studio, but if you're writing manual test cases for QA folk to follow, or automated tests that need babysiting by QA people, then you'll want to use MTM.

Comment: thanks. how about running the automated coded ui tests? I mean, if I work to MTM can I run the test methods using code? or they can be run only by MTM?

Comment: @H.Z. My understanding is that tests written against the Microsoft Testing platform can be executed in both Visual Studio and MTM.

Comment: Can I generate all the log, diagnostics, etc that MTM generated in the VS?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft test manager (mtm) is a good place to organize manual tests. I don’t record tests from mtm because it sometimes has trouble identifying controls on a page. To get action recording, I suggest hand coding the tests using coded ui test framework in visual studio and linking them with manual test cases that were created in mtm

Answer (score 0):

the most amazing part in MTM, that

1. you will be able to organize your test and iterations ,
2. it help in writing the bugs depending n the format of test case .
3. make sure you had cover all the required parts using [code coverage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2012/11/28/code-coverage-in-microsoft-test-manager-in-visual-studio-update-1/)
4. you will be able to check where the [test impact](https://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-with-tfs-enable-test-impact-analysis/) has happen
5. recording test case , but I don't like it, but if you need to automate you can integrate with Selenium